# Using Dagger2 with Database

Tags: android, database, nullpointerexception, dagger

I am trying to use dagger2 and database in my android application. I can not access the database class with the inject operation. The Database db object I created is returning null. I am new on dagger2. Thanks for any help.

This is my database class.

```
public  class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


@Inject
public Database(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
    super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void createTables(){..}

public void clearAllTables() {...}

public void dropTable(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + tableName);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {.. }  .. }
```

This is my module.

```
@Module abstract public class DatabaseModule {

private Application application;
public DatabaseModule(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
}
@Provides
@ApplicationContext
Context provideContext() {
    return application;
}}
```

And component

```
@ActivityScope @Subcomponent public interface DatabaseSubcomponent {

@ApplicationContext
Context getContext();

Database getDb(); }
```

Db object returns null as follows :

```
   @Inject
Database db;
```

I will be grateful if you tell me where I made a mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a scope annotator for yourself **@DatabaseScope.java**

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DatabaseScope {
}
```

And then the **DatabaseModule.java** should provide context and database objects which is your module(during injection of database object dagger automatically injects context for you from the object graph)

```
@Module
public class DatabaseModule {

    private Application application;

    public DatabaseModule(Application application){

        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseScope
    Context provideContext(){
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @DatabaseScope
    Database provideDatabase(Context context){
        return new Database(context);
    }
}
```

And then the **DatabaseComponent.java** . You need not annotate this as a subcomponent

```
@DatabaseScope
@Component(modules = {DatabaseModule.class})
public interface DatabaseComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

and then your **database.java**

```
public  class Database extends Object {

    public Database(Context context) {
        Log.e("database creted"," ");
    }

    String getmessage(){
        return "jenison";
    }

}
```

and finally inject this in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    Database db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseComponent component=DaggerDatabaseComponent.builder().databaseModule(new DatabaseModule(getApplication())).build();
        component.inject(this);
        Log.e("test"," "+db.getmessage());
    }
}
```